# USB stick product code is recognised but not "No Medium"

Tags: usb-drive, gnome-disk-utility

I have a new USB stick that should be 1 TB. The program [Disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks) shows a null product code ("VendorCo ProductCode (2.00)") and shows "No Medium" with no size, no media, and no contents. How do I fix it?

[image: Disks screenshot]

Comment: It only has 1 option: "Edit Mount Options"

Comment: GParted doesn't even recognise that there is storage there. The command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` returns: `dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': No medium found`. I will try to format it on another machine.

Comment: Using another machine running windows didn't work. By the way, I got the USB stick 2 days ago and it was running fine until yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all you get from [Disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks) is *Edit Mount Options*, with no real vendor, model, size, or media info, and gparted does not even recognize it, and Windows won't recognize it, then it has failed. Return it to the vendor for replacement

Answer (score 1):

fake disk detected.
Today so manu fake flash drive and portable drive on the market.
please be aware