# USB stick not a block device

Tags: usb-drive, gnome-disk-utility

I am having problems with my USB stick. From the disks utility I can see its size, model and Serial Number but I can't make a NTFS partition on it. Previously I had another problem with the same USB stick [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188696/usb-stick-product-code-is-recognised-but-not-no-medium). How can I fix it?

```
$ sudo mkfs -t ntfs /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb is not a block device.
Refusing to make a filesystem here!
```

[image: USB stick info from ubuntu's disks utility]

Comment: Is the size 1TB? (I mean, is Disks showing the correct size?)

Comment: You really shouldn't make filesystem on the device (/dev/sdb) but on the first partition (/dev/sdb1). If that partition doesn't exists, create it with parted (in terminal) or gparted (in Desktop).

Comment: The USB stick is supposed to be 1TB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Wipe the first mibibyte

First you can wipe the first mibibyte with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). This can remove data, that might confuse the tools, that you want to use later.

If you run standard Ubuntu live, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

### Create partition table and file system

I suggest that you first create a partition table (new GPT or old MSDOS), and then create a partition `/dev/sdb1`, and then create a file system in the partition.

- You can do it with command line tools, `fdisk` or `gdisk` depending on which partition table you want, and then `mkfs`
- You can do it easier with `gparted`, if you have a graphical desktop environment

  - Device - Create Partition Table ...
  - Partition - New
  - Double-check that things are correct
  - Click on the tick icon to perform the actions

### Final comment

If the actions above do not work, I think the drive hardware is damaged.